# How to read from a text file and move onto next line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am making a program that will scan a text file to find all the ints, and then print them out, and move onto the next line

Ive tried turning if statements into while loops to try to improve, but my code runs through the text file, writes out all the numbers, but fails at the end where it runs into a java.util.NoSuchElementException. If I have a text file with the numbers 
1 2 3 
fifty 5, 
then it prints out 
1 
2 
3 
5 
But it crashes right at the end everytime

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class filterSort
{
    public static void main()
    {
       container(); 

    }
    public static void run()
    {


    }
    public static void container()
    {   Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        int temp;
        try
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a file name: ");
            String fileName = console.nextLine();
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            while(file.hasNextLine())
            {
                while(file.hasNextInt())

                {
                    temp = file.nextInt(); 
                    System.out.println(temp);                    
                }
                 file.next();                        
            }

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found.");

        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 file.next();
```

with

```
if(file.hasNextLine())
   file.nextLine();
```

Every time you try to advance on a scanner, you must check if it has the token.

Comment: It just prints `1 2 3` with the change you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the program which is working for me . Also it is good practice to close all the resources once done and class name should be camel case. It's all good practice and standards

```
package com.ros.employees;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class FileTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        container(); 
    }

    public static void container()
    {   Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        int temp;
        try
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a file name: ");
            String fileName = console.nextLine();
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            while(file.hasNextLine())
            {
                while(file.hasNextInt())
                {
                    temp = file.nextInt(); 
                    System.out.println(temp);                    
                }
                if(file.hasNextLine())
                     file.next();    
            }
            file.close();
            console.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }

    }
}
```